# How to compare two very large tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, comparison, rows

I'm pretty new to SQL, so I'm using MySQL workbench, and I have two very large tables (around 900K rows in each) and I want to compare the tables. Note both tables have same number of rows.

Each table has 16 columns, and I'm only interested in comparing a few of the columns. So say the tables have columns DataID, a, b, c, d ,e and I want to see if the value in columns c and d and e are the same in table A and table B for each row based on DataID.

In each table I have a DataID column which makes for a point of reference for comparing rows in each table, so for example I want to compare the row with DataID=444 in table A with the row with the same DataID in table B and see if the columns I'm interested are the same.

The process has to be repeated for all 900k rows and I guess would help if I could write the results somewhere.

I would appreciate any help, and I'm glad to answer any questions if I've been too confusing.

Comment: Hey there. We'd gladly help you given some code to build upon. What is your present query looking like?

Comment: Hello, aside from using simple select statements i'm not awfully proficient in SQL. I guess i have an idea of what needs to be done: I have to look at at each table where the DataID in A = DataID in B, then compare if the value in the columns i'm interested in are the same. In the end I'd like to display the DataID's where the rows were different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to return table of rows with the same DataID and has all the same values in c,d,e use following query:

```
SELECT 
t1.c, t2.c, t1.d, t2.d, t1.e, t2.e
FROM
table1 t1
    INNER JOIN
table2 t2 ON t1.DataId = t2.DataId
WHERE
t1.c = t2.c AND t1.d = t2.d
    AND t1.e = t2.e
```

If you want table where any value (c,d or e) are same use `t1.c = t2.c or t1.d = t2.d or t1.e = t2.e` in `WHERE` clause.
To get table with all different values use following in `WHERE` clause `t1.c <> t2.c AND t1.d <> t2.d AND t1.e <> t2.e`
To get table where any value is different use following in `WHERE` clause `t1.c <> t2.c OR t1.d <> t2.d OR t1.e <> t2.e`
To save result use following query:

```
INSERT INTO SaveTable SELECT 
t1.c, t2.c, t1.d, t2.d, t1.e, t2.e
FROM
table1 t1
    INNER JOIN
table2 t2 ON t1.DataId = t2.DataId
WHERE
t1.c <> t2.c AND t1.d <> t2.d AND t1.e <> t2.e
```

To add insert values in other case just modify where clause and a just values in `select` clause.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. This appears to "work". The quotation marks because I think due to the large amount of data, the query errors with 'error 2013 lost connection to mysql server during query". Is there a way to somehow breakdown this query so it wont have so much strain on MySQL?

Comment: My Query

`INSERT INTO mt_vs_us SELECT 
t1.RunID,
t1.CaseID,
t1.DataID,
t1.OrderNumber,
t1.CategoryCode,
t1.COD,
t1.Region,
t1.PostalCode,
t1.SalePrice,
t1.CDN,
t1.Tax,
t1.IntShipping,
t1.IntHandling,
t1.Duty,
t1.Brokerage,
t1.OrderData,
t1.Ref,
t1.RunDate,
t1.Status,
t1.Details
FROM
order_results_mt t1
    INNER JOIN
order_results_us t2 ON t1.DataId = t2.DataId
WHERE
t1.Tax <> t2.Tax or t1.IntShipping <> t2.IntShipping or t1.IntHandling <> t2.IntHandling or t1.Duty <> t2.Duty or t1.Brokerage <> t2.Brokerage`

Comment: You can try making this query in portions. I mean for DataId from 1 to 10000, from 1001 to 2000 and so on. Or try to increase query working time in settings.

Comment: I see, I'll take a look! I encountered a 10 year old MySQL bug during the process where the ibdata1 file in mysql grows and takes up huge amounts of disk space (60 GB at this point)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding it correctly, you need only those records where DataID, c, d and e columns have the same values.
In this case the following statement will get you the results:

```
SELECT TableA.DataID, 
TableA.c, 
TableA.d, 
TableA.e 
-- add any other columns to the selection list if needed

INTO result_table
FROM TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.DataID = TableB.DataID
WHERE TableA.c = TableB.c
AND TableA.d = TableB.d
AND TableA.e = TableB.e
```

As far as I know, there is no better way (from performance point of view) than using a simple INNER JOIN statement for solving this.
It should be fast even on huge datasets, assuming that DataID is a Primary Key in both TableA and TableB.

Comment: You have error in your insert syntax. See my answer below.

Comment: True, however I'm not editing it, because you already added the answer, just one small remark: Why are you inserting the columns from both A and B tables when they have the same values in all those columns? I think it would save some space and time if we would store only the columns from TableA

Comment: True, I was writing inserting piece with all different values in mind, it would be more relevant that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join to compare the data

A small snippet would be

```
SELECT table_A.a, table_B.a, ...... 
FROM table_A
INNER JOIN table_B
  ON table_A.DataID = table_B.DataID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this task a lot, but you will read many data. If that's ok, just execute 2 SELECTs, and calculate their MD5. Then you can compare the MD5.

Getting the Md5 from the command line client on Linux is very easy:

```
\P md5sum
SELECT ...
```

Doing via a program is a bit longer, but after all, you just need 2 loops.